# YouTrack disable mannual time tracking

Tags: youtrack

We are using youtrack timetracking workflow to track time by changing task status (in progress -> time ticking, resolved -> time tracked).

We would like to disable manual entry of time tracking entries and leave it only for project Admins. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no such feature. What you can do is you can create a workflow that will detect if a workitem is added when no status change occure and throw an error.